# Three.js/Aframe fix rotation around sphere

Tags: math, three.js, rotation, aframe

I have developed a feature that is in effect a sphere that follows the camera, so you can animate the sphere so the desired part of a 360 video mapped to the inside of the sphere is in front of the camera.

I want you animate the pan and tilt and so the sphere animates to that position, so it's kind of following you. I.e. you look left, the sphere animates left to follow you. Same with up and down.

```
this._prevVec = this.el.object3D.rotation.clone()

this._sourceVec = new THREE.Vector3(
    this._cameraParent.object3D.rotation.x + THREE.MathUtils.degToRad( this._rotationAnimation.x  ),
    this._cameraParent.object3D.rotation.y + THREE.MathUtils.degToRad( this._rotationAnimation.y  ),
    this._cameraParent.object3D.rotation.z + THREE.MathUtils.degToRad( this._rotationAnimation.z  )
)

this._deltaY = floatModulo( this._sourceVec.y - this._prevVec.y, -this._half, this._half )
this._deltaX = floatModulo( this._sourceVec.x - this._prevVec.x, -this._half, this._half )

this._rotationSpeedY = three.Math.mapLinear(
  this._deltaY, -this.data.springAngle, this.data.springAngle,
  -this.data.peakSpeed, this.data.peakSpeed
)

this._rotationSpeedX = three.Math.mapLinear(
  this._deltaX, -this.data.springAngle, this.data.springAngle,
  -this.data.peakSpeed, this.data.peakSpeed
)

  this.el.object3D.rotation.set(
      this._prevVec.x + this._rotationSpeedX * timeDelta,
      this._prevVec.y + this._rotationSpeedY * timeDelta,
      THREE.MathUtils.degToRad(this._rotation.z),
      "YXZ"
    )
```

This works fine for panning(Y), but only sometimes works for tilt because they're changing depending on which way it's going.

I tried using a Quaternion and slerping - but the problem is the same.

The other thing I was thinking was 2 entities, and rotating them independently.

I only want to animate the pan/tilt values, I'm not sure how to represent that?

EDIT

I tried to get it working with a Quarternion

```
this._prevQuat = this.el.object3D.quaternion.clone()

this._sourceVec = new THREE.Vector3(
    this._cameraParent.object3D.rotation.x + THREE.MathUtils.degToRad( this._rotation.x  ),
    this._cameraParent.object3D.rotation.y + THREE.MathUtils.degToRad( this._rotation.y  ),
    this._cameraParent.object3D.rotation.z + THREE.MathUtils.degToRad( this._rotation.z  )
)

this._sourceQuat = this._cameraParent.object3D.quaternion.clone()

this._deltaY = floatModulo( this._sourceQuat.y - this._prevQuat.y, -this._half, this._half )
this._deltaX = floatModulo( this._sourceQuat.x - this._prevQuat.x, -this._half, this._half )

this._rotationSpeedY = three.Math.mapLinear(
  this._deltaY, -this.data.springAngle, this.data.springAngle,
  -this.data.peakSpeed, this.data.peakSpeed
)
this._rotationSpeedX = three.Math.mapLinear(
  this._deltaX, -this.data.springAngle, this.data.springAngle,
  -this.data.peakSpeed, this.data.peakSpeed
)

//this.el.object3D.rotation.y = this._prevVec.y + this._rotationSpeedY * timeDelta

this.el.object3D.quaternion.slerp(new THREE.Quaternion(
  this._prevQuat.x + this._rotationSpeedX * timeDelta,
  this._prevQuat.y + this._rotationSpeedY * timeDelta,
  this._prevQuat.z,
  this._prevQuat.w
), 1)
```

This kind of works - but seems to change the shape or position of the sphere!? But the movement is closer.

Comment: It looks like you're running into [gimbal-lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock). It happens when trying to set rotations using 3-dimensional Euler angles, you should look into using 4-dimensional [Quaternions](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Quaternion.setFromAxisAngle)

Comment: Thanks no it's not gimbal lock. It's fixing one axis while allowing the other to update.